# what's the good practice to program with dynamic inputs in dplyr 0.3

Tags: join, eval, shiny, dplyr

My original intention to do this is to integrate dplyr with shiny

Prior to 0.3 I have used eval(parse(text=....)), do.call() approach.

In 0.3, I saw two more options, for example:

```
var <- c('disp','hp')
select_(mtcars,.dots = as.lazy_dots(var))
select(mtcars,one_of(var))
```

but which one is better? I intended to pass the selectInput values from Shiny app to do data transformations through dplyr.

Another question, what will be the right way to join two different dataset with dynamic but different key column? Is there anything I can leverage in 0.3?

for example
col_a, col_b are key variables to join from datasets a & b

```
left_join(dataset_a,dataset_b, by=c(col_a=col_b))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After a few attempts, here is my solution for the 2nd question, use a function to create a named vector, and then feed to left_join.

```
joinCol_a = xxx
joinCol_b = xxx

f <- function(a,b){
  vec <- c(b)
  names(vec) <- a
  return(vec)
}
left_join(dataset_a,dataset_b,by=f(joinCol_a,joinCol_b))
```

I know it's not the best solution but this is what I can think of so far.